# Gradle error when isLightTheme Attribute declared in two libraries error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, commonsware-cwac, aviary

I am building an Android project that uses two external libraries: 
cwac-mediarouter and AviarySDK.

Both of these libraries declare `isLightTheme` Attribute and I am not able to build the project, as Gradle build fails. Prior to getting the latest version of the AviarySDK, this issue did not exist, so it seems that AviarySDK introduced this attribute in their latest SDK.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is the Gradle error, it's not really clear where this Attribute is being declared based on the error, but after removing cwac-mediarouter library from the project build (and commenting out the relevant code) I was able to do a successful Gradle build. The file to which this error refers simply defines a bunch of colors, nothing else, in fact if remove this file from the project, the error will point to a different xml file.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Attribute \"isLightTheme\" has already been defined","sourcePath":"/Users/gkipnis/repos/floomitandroidclientcamera3/floomItNewCamera/src/main/res/values/colors.xml","position":{"startLine":1},"original":""}
```

Comment: Could you post the actual error message that you are getting from the Gradle Console?

Comment: @CommonsWare I've updated my original question. Thank You.

Comment: This isn't strictly a problem with `cwac-mediarouter`, insofar as you should get the same error with the official `mediarouter-v7` library. I did not alter resources at all IIRC. This is why I usually prefix my resources, to avoid this sort of collision. That being said, I have no clue how you would resolve it.

Comment: @CommonsWare After digging some more, I can see that AviarySDK is using appcomp-v7 (in which isLightTheme is declared). Is it true that when cwac-mediarouter is used, that appcomp-v7 should not be used? Thank You.

Comment: "Is it true that when cwac-mediarouter is used, that appcomp-v7 should not be used?" -- well, the point of `cwac-mediarouter` is to avoid `appcompat-v7`. The stock `mediarouter-v7` library is designed for use with `appcompat-v7`. Ordinarily, if you want to use `appcompat-v7`, you would use `mediarouter-v7`; if you want to use the native action bar instead, you would use `cwac-mediarouter`. You would have to ask the Aviary folk why they need `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: @CommonsWare is appcompat-v7 only needed for the mediarouter or other components as well? Because if it's the latter, and I need some component from the appcompat-v7, other than the mediarouter, how can I use that component if I am also using cwac-mediarouter? Thank You.

Comment: "is appcompat-v7 only needed for the mediarouter or other components as well?" -- as I indicated, you would have to ask Aviary why they depend upon `appcompat-v7`.